# How to create SSAS server in Multidimensional mode?

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services

How to create an SSAS server in Multidimensional mode?
I have created an SSAS server using Azure. But it was created in tabular mode. I can't change the mode.
I need a SSAS server in multidimensional mode.
Please help me out.

Comment: Did you create a VM or did you provision Azure Analysis Services (the one where you connect via asazure://...)?

Comment: i used azure analysis services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provisioned Azure Analysis Services (the one where you connect via asazure://...) but Multidimensional isn't currently supported. Please [vote](https://web.archive.org/web/20130525153920/https://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/) for it.

For other peoples' use in the future... if you created a VM and accidentally installed SSAS In Tabular mode then you can edit msmdsrv.ini and set DeploymentMode to 0 and restart the SSAS Service (kind of the opposite of what Cathy Dumas did [here](https://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/)). That will switch the instance to Multidimensional mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info @GregGalloway.